# Find steps to find given value of index

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I am new to SO - I have a question which I was asked in interview and which for life of me I am not able to wrap my head around. I can solve it with while/for loop but interviewer specifically asked not to use them I even discussed with few friends of mine but unable to solve it. If someone can provide pointers.

Question is: 
for given array

```
s[] = {5,1,0,4,2,3}
```

1. length of array is not given.
2. If length of array is 5 content
   is guaranteed to be between 0 to 5.
3. There is no repetition of
   numbers.

Sample example length(s, 3) 
- a[3] = 4 , a[4] = 2, a[2] = 0, a[0] = 5, a[5] =3 returns length of 4 .

For given condition write subroutine int length (s, 3) - to find the number of steps it takes to find given value -

**Additional conditions**

1. You cannot use any loop statements like for, while and so on -
2. You cannot use any global or static variables.
3. You cannot call other routines inside this routine
4. You cannot modify given function parameters - it stays length (s, n) only
5. You cannot change original array too

Comment: Have you considered recursion?

Comment: did - but got stuck with aspect of incrementing value - i believe i would need global value here which i cant use

Comment: *3. You cannot call other routines inside this routine* So the function can call itself?

Comment: @this yes - when I tried that he didnt object to that approach

Comment: What the question is really asking is, what is the length of the cycle that starts at the selected index. You *need* to have additional information to check if you reached the end of the cycle, i.e., the starting index. Currently your function only provides information about the next index. The solution with your constraints doesn't exist.

Comment: @this - index value is guaranteed to be present - in that case end of cycle would be finding the index ?

Comment: @this - end of cycle would only be needed if index value asked to find is not present - would that be correct - or am I missing something ?

Comment: @ifelse A cycle is guaranteed to exist. The function doesn't have any other information apart from the current index. You are the function. Ask yourself how do you know if you already completed the cycle or not? You cannot know without any additional information. (If you don't understand what I said, take a piece of paper and try to end the cycle limiting yourself to information provided by the function parameters. )

Comment: @this - Seems there is something wrong in my understanding for sure - As I was thinking of breaking the recursion when s[x] == x -- till then it would stay in recursion loop - Again the issue is I wont be able to find the length :) .. can you help me understand the part that I am missing - so that I re-collect If I have missed something while asking question

Comment: Is there a limit on the possible array length?

Comment: it was interview question :) - so I guess we can assume that- I didnt ask but I assumed it is limited

Comment: Coding interviews that involve this kind of puzzles are never about the puzzle itself. It's either about your way of approaching pointless obstacles, or about acknowledging the smug grin on the face of the person who came up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution that does not modify the array at all, but hides an extra parameter inside top 16 bits of x:

```
int length(int *s, int x){
    int start = (x >> 16) - 1;
    if (start < 0)
        start = x;
    if (s[x] == start)
       return 0;
    return 1 + length(s, ((start + 1) << 16) + s[x]);   
}
```

This will fail if there are too many elements in the array, but I suspect any other recursive solution is likely to hit a stack overflow by that point in any case.

Comment: This solution modifies s

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer eventually no I didnt crack it but found it online :) .. Here is the solution

```
int length(int * s, int x){
    if(s[x] < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        s[x] = -s[x];
        int len = length(s, -s[x]);
        s[x] = -s[x];
        return len + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: So does constraint 5 actually mean "the final contents of the array must equal the initial contents of the array" rather than "you cannot write to the original array"?

Comment: API given to me was -->  int length(int * s, int x)   - and it did not have constant associated to it , so I think we can modify the array as long as its intact - Again I dont know i was not able to solve in interview :) .. it's just I found a solution which does that so posted the solution. b@PeterdeRivaz solution would be more correct if add the condition of not writing to original array - again above solution is not modifying it.. but again Peter's solution would be more elegant

Comment: This solution is violating the 5th constraint. The array was changed or modified. The correct phrasing for the constraint should be: the array must retain the same values, after the function call.

Comment: seems to violate constraint regarding modifies s.

Answer (score -1):

i don't think it contradicts with any of your conditions. i just didn't use the array as a parameter (that isn't a problem actually, you can modify it yourself)

```
int s[] = {5,1,0,4,2,3};
bool col[100]; ///to check cycle

int rec(int n)
{
    if(col[n])return 0;
    col[n]=true;
    int sum=0;
    sum = 1+rec(s[n]);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: 2. You cannot use any global or static variables.

Comment: do you mean the `col` array?? @this

Comment: I said you cannot use global or static variables. You are using col and s as a global variable.

Answer (score -1):

The interviewer is probing your understanding of algorithms and programming paradigms, trying to understand your training, background, and depth. The interviewer has a *challenging task; identifying capable developers with minimal evidence.* Thus the interviewer presents a constructed problem that *(they hope)* elicits the desired knowledge *(does candidate X know how to solve problem Y, or understand concept Z)* perhaps because the interviewer believes the desired answer indicates the candidate knows the expected body of knowledge.

Modern languages provide several repetition structures (commands, statements), some which pre-test (check condition before entering statement-block), and some which post-test (check condition after performing statement block at least once). Here are examples,

Pre-test

```
while(condition) statement-block
for(initializer;condition;step) statement-block
```

Post-test

```
do statement-block while(condition)
repeat statement-block until(condition)
do statement-block until(condition)
```

These can all be written as conditional (choice) structures with branching (goto),

Pre-test

```
label:
if(condition)
    statement-block;
    goto label;
else
    nil;
endif
```

Post-test

```
label:
statement-block;
if(condition)
    goto label;
endif
```

You can also use recursion, where you call the same function as long as condition holds (or until condition met, depending upon positive or negative logic),

Pre-test

```
function recurse(args)
    if(condition)
        statement-block
        recurse(revised args);
    endif
    return
end #function
```

Post-test

```
function recurse(args)
    statement-block
    if(condition)
        recurse(revised args);
    endif
    return;
end
```

You would learn about recursion in an algorithms, or perhaps a computability course.  You would learn about conditional branching in a compiler, high performance computing, or systems class. Your compiler course might examine techniques for detecting 'tail-recursion', and how to rewrite the function call into a loop.

Here is the problem, restated,

```
given array, s[] = {5,1,0,4,2,3}
array length unknown
content between [0 .. length], not repeated, no duplicates
write subroutine which provides the number of steps to find given value
```

That is,

```
int length( array s, int member ) --> position
```

Examine the conditions (constraints) on the problem,

- Array length unknown - *Solution must work for variable range of inputs*
- Cannot use loop statements (for, while, etc) - *This suggests either the interviewer wants conditional branch or recursion.*
- Cannot use global or static variables - *Does this suggest interviewer wants a recursive/functional-programming solution? Conditional-branch also provides this.*
- Cannot call other routines inside this routine - *Does interviewer mean functions other than same function, or call any function (what does interviewer mean by 'other').*
- Cannot modify function parameters, stays length(s,n) - *Declaring local (stack) variables is allowed. This could mean pass by value, make a local copy, etc. But not destructive modifications.*
- Cannot change original array - *Definitely no destructive modifications. Possible 'hint' (ok to make local copy?), or further indication that you should use conditional-branch?*

Here are two solutions, and a test driver (note, I have named them lengthi, iterative, and lengthr, recursive).

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* conditional branch */
int lengthi( int s[], int member )
{
    int position=0;
    AGAIN:
    if( s[position] == member ) return(position);
    ++position;
    goto AGAIN;
    return(-1);
}

/* recursive */
int lengthr( int s[], int member )
{
    if( s[0] == member ) return(0);
    return( 1+length(s+1,member) );
}

int
main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int s1[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int s2[] = {1,2,3,4,9,8,7,6,0,5};
    int s3[] = {2,4,6,8,0,1,3,5,7,9};

    printf("%d at %d\n",3,lengthr(s1,3));
    printf("%d at %d\n",3,lengthr(s2,3));
    printf("%d at %d\n",3,lengthr(s3,3));
    printf("%d at %d\n",3,lengthi(s1,3));
    printf("%d at %d\n",3,lengthi(s2,3));
    printf("%d at %d\n",3,lengthi(s3,3));
}
```

Since we are supposed to find the number of steps (iterations, function calls), that is asking for the ordinal position in the list, not the C index (zero based) position.

This is an interview question, and not a programming problem (per se), so probably better suited for the [Programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site. *I might give the interviewer an entertaining answer, or their desired answer.*

Comment: Note that a very similar question is answered here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/303242/is-there-anything-that-can-be-done-with-recursion-that-cant-be-done-with-loops

Comment: Oh, I misspelled AGAIN (the goto target), but hey, I never use goto. Please run the test I have added, and you will see that the functions do return the correct number of steps.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill - Thank you for the detailed answer - I will keep the points in mind - Appreciate it !!!

Comment: You completely misunderstood the question. I suggest try to look at other answers and the example OP provided.